# Error writing parameters into SQL tabel with Pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, sql-server-express

I am trying to write into my SQL tabel that contains the parameters "time, camID, id, x, y, height" - with the following function:

```
database_connection = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server}',
                      server = server, database = database, UID=user, PWD=password)

# ---- Write to SQL database function ----    
def WriteToSql(timestamp, cameraid, objectid, x, y, height):
    
    # Define SQL INSERT statement
    add_camera_coordinates = "INSERT INTO camera_coordinates(ObservationTimestamp, CameraID, ObjectId, X, Y, Height, CreatedAt) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"    
    
    insert_tuple = (timestamp, cameraid, objectid, x, y, height, datetime.datetime.now())
    
    database_cursor = database_connection.cursor()     
    database_connection.commit();
```

Unfortunately, this function would return the error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 7 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Does anyone know how I write these parameters with PyODBC? Before that, I tried using Pymssql, but havent found a solution there neither.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Because PyODBC uses `?` as parameter markers. You're using `%s`, which is not a parameter marker.

Comment: Thank you Larnu for you reply. How is the syntax, can I just replace the "%s" with "?" in this line: add_camera_coordinates = "INSERT INTO camera_coordinates(ObservationTimestamp, CameraID, ObjectId, X, Y, Height, CreatedAt) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" ?

Comment: `%s` should be `?`.

Comment: See the example in the documentation: [Insert a row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15#insert-a-row)